# Dell Laptop Inspiron 13 with Ubuntu 20,04 TouchPad and keyboard not working after lid closed

Tags: keyboard, suspend, touchpad, 20.04, power-management

I have the Laptop mentioned above and it works great I can shut it down and reboot it and I can suspend it with the power button or by using suspend in the program but if I close the lid and open it back up the touch pad and keyboard will not work and I have to force reboot I have tried to do everything I have found to resolve this by editing grub and also restarting drivers but I am at a lose can someone please help

Thanks Mark